# Why don't I get "A link to the past" hat though I have the Excavator badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

I have earned [Excavator badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator?userid=1654241) ("Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months. ") but when I go on the [Winter Bash site](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), it says "You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet." for the ["A link to the past" hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/a-link-to-the-past) which requires to "edit a post more than 90 days old".

Does anyone know why I don't get a fun hat?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to edit a post more than 90 days old *during* Winterbash.

Comment: It wasn't that clear on the Winter Bash site, thank you! And some hats do not require that you meet certain conditions during Winter Bash (e.g. Old Hat which requires that you signed up on the site during its first month of existence).